# How to raise an event when unit testing asynchronous method in my case?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I use MS-Test, moq 4.18.2 and FileSystem (System.IO.Abstractions) 17.0.24 for my tests.

I think I wrote a correct test for *InfoLoader_LoadInfoAsync*. But, I don't understand how to write a test for `MyViewModel::StartLoadInfoAsync` to check that `InfoList` was populated correctly. It seems that I have to duplicate instantiation and configuration of `InfoLoader` as I did in `InfoLoader_LoadInfoAsync`. Is there a way around this? How such things are usually tested?

```
public abstract class IInfoLoader
{
    public event Action<MyInfo> InfoLoaded;
    public abstract Task LoadInfoAsync();

    protected void OnInfoLoaded(MyInfo info)
    {
        InfoLoaded?.Invoke(info);
    }
}
public class InfoLoader : IInfoLoader
{
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    private readonly string _path;

    public InfoLoader(string path, IFileSystem fileSystem) {...}
    
    public async override Task LoadInfoAsync()
    {
        foreach (var data in await _fileSystem.File.ReadAllLinesAsync(_path))
            OnInfoLoaded(new MyInfo(...));
    }
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    private IInfoLoader _infoLoader;
    public ObservableCollection<MyInfo> InfoList { get; }

    public MyViewModel(IInfoLoader infoLoader) { ... }

    public Task StartLoadInfoAsync()
    {
        _infoLoader.InfoLoaded += (info) => InfoList.Add(info);
        return _infoLoader.LoadInfoAsync();
    }
}
```

**Tests**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task InfoLoader_LoadInfoAsync_Success()
{
    var path = "...";
    var lines = new string[] { "name1", "name2" };
    var expectedInfoList = new List<MyInfo>();
    foreach(var line in lines)
        expectedInfoList.Add(new MyInfo(line));

    var fileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
    fileSystem.Setup(fs => fs.File.ReadAllLinesAsync(path, CancellationToken.None))
                .ReturnsAsync(lines);

    var actualInfoList = new List<MyInfo>();
    var infoLoader = new InfoLoader(path, fileSystem.Object);
    infoLoader.InfoLoaded += (info) => actualInfoList.Add(info);
    await infoLoader.LoadInfoAsync();

    // Assert that items in expectedInfoList and actualInfoList are equal
}
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyViewModel_StartLoadInfoAsync_Success()
{
    var expectedInfoList = new List<MyInfo>();
    
    // WHAT DO I DO HERE? DO I CREATE AND CONFIGURE infoLoader LIKE in "InfoLoader_LoadInfoAsync" TEST?
    
    var vm = new MyViewModel(infoLoader.Object);
    await vm.StartLoadInfoAsync();
    actualInfoList = vm.InfoList;
    
    // Assert that items in expectedInfoList and actualInfoList are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the view model depends on the `IInfoLoader` abstraction, it can be mocked to behave as expected when the desired member is invoked.

Review the comments in the following example

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task MyViewModel_StartLoadInfoAsync_Success() {
    //Arrange
    var info = new MyInfo();
    List<MyInfo> expectedInfoList = new List<MyInfo>() { info };
    
    // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
    var dependency = new Mock<IInfoLoader>(); //mock the dependency
    
    dependency
        // When LoadInfoAsync is invoked
        .Setup(_ => _.LoadInfoAsync())
        // Use callback to raise event passing the custom arguments expected by the event delegate
        .Callback(() => dependency.Raise(_ => _.InfoLoaded += null, info))
        // Then allow await LoadInfoAsync to complete properly
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask); 
    
    MyViewModel subject = new MyViewModel(dependency.Object);
    
    //Act
    await subject.StartLoadInfoAsync();
    
    
    //Assert
    List<MyInfo> actualInfoList = subject.InfoList;
    
    actualInfoList.Should().NotBeEmpty()
        And.BeEquivalentTo(expectedInfoList); //Using FluentAssertions
    
}
```

Note how a `Callback` is used to capture when `LoadInfoAsync` is invoked by the subject so that an event can be raised by the mock, allowing the subject under test to flow to completion as desired

Reference [MOQ Quickstart: Events](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events)

Comment: I tried this code, but I get `System.ArgumentException: 'Unsupported expression: _ => _...
The next member after the last one shown above is non-virtual, sealed, or not visible to the proxy factory.'` exception when callback is called. Do you have an idea why? After debugging it shows that it fails on `_.InfoLoaded += null`. The StackTrace shows `at Moq.ActionObserver.ReconstructExpression[T](Action'1 action, Object[] ctorArgs)`

Comment: Ahhh, I think the exception is because the event is not virtual since the abstraction is an abstract class and not an interface. Just to trouble shoot make the event virtual to see if the error goes away. Might need to change the approach if that is the case. I misread the `IInfoLoader` thinking it was an interface based on naming convention

Comment: yep, the virtual event fixed the issue. Is there a way to not make it virtual? Also, is there a way to be able to `Raise` the event more than one time?

Comment: do you have an idea how to solve this without using `virtual event`? One of the solutions I came up with was moving `InfoLoaded` event to separate interface `INotifyInfoLoaded` and make `IInfoLoader` implement it `abstract class IInfoLoader : INotifyInfoLoaded`. Is this a good workaround?

Comment: @theateist yes that is actually a better design as apposed to a work around. By having it as part of the an interface it simplifies the abstraction. I suggest you add your solution as a self answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test `StartLoadInfoAsync` you need an instance of `MyViewModel`, so you should:

1. Create this instance.
2. Invoke the method `StartLoadInfoAsync`.
3. Assert that its state is according to what you need.

Now obviously you have a dependency, which is `InfoLoader`, so you have two options:

1. Create and configure a new instance of `InfoLoader`
2. Mock `InfoLoader` so you can test `MyViewModel` independently of `InfoLoader`.

The second approach is what you may want to follow, this way you do not need to configure again `InfoLoader`, mock the `FileSystem` and so on.

You only need to create a mock of `InfoLoader` and setup its calls, just like you did with the `FileSystem`.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm asking. I'm not sure how to mock `InfoLoader` without mocking `IFileSystem` again and providing `lines` again like I did in `InfoLoader_LoadInfoAsync_Success()`. It seems that I have to duplicate. Can you show how to mock `InfoLoader` without duplicating? I already started the test in `MyViewModel_StartLoadInfoAsync_Success()`. For `StartLoadInfoAsync` to success the `InfoLoaded` event should be raised. And, I'm not sure how to do that in unit test.